# How can I adapt this previous script answer to my target pages?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I want the browser to be able to highlight correct answers to questions in green.
I found [**an answer that seems to be the right idea** (How can I automatically select specific radio buttons with Greasemonkey?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025270/) but I don't know enough javascript to use it.

My HTML code is shown in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDThC/6/).

Desired output example should look something like this:

> [image]

How do I adapt that other answer to my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var questionTxt =` and `var ansForThisQ =` lines must be adapted to your target page's specific HTML.

Likewise, the code inside the `ansForThisQ.each (...` loop must also be tailored.

Given your sample HTML has the structure:

```
<div class="soru-content">
    <div class="point" style="margin-right:0px">
        <span><img src="IMG_URL"/></span>
    </div>
    <div class="soru">
        <p>How many countries will participate in the games?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="ANS_URL1"><span>12</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ANS_URL2"><span>204</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ANS_URL3"><span>552</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="ANS_URL4"><span>715</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the adapted script code would be:

```
var answerKey   = [
      { q: "How many countries will participate in the games?", a: "204" }
    , { q: "when do olympics start in london", a: "July 27" }
    // etc.
];

//--- Loop through the question(s) on the page and answer then if possible.
var questionTxt = $("div.soru-content div.soru p");

questionTxt.each ( function () {
    var bFoundAnswer    = false;
    var answerTxt       = getAnswer (this.textContent);
    if (answerTxt) {
        //--- We have the answer text, now find the matching radio button and select it.
        var ansForThisQ     = $(this).parent ().find ("ul a span");

        ansForThisQ.each ( function () {
            var zRegExp     = new RegExp (answerTxt, 'i');
            if (zRegExp.test (this.textContent) ) {
                bFoundAnswer    = true;
                $(this).css     ("background", "lime");
                return false;   // End loop
            }
        } );
    }
    else {
        alert ("I don't know how to answer: '" + this.textContent + "'");
        $(this).css ("background", "pink");
    }
    if ( answerTxt  &&  ! bFoundAnswer) {
        alert ("The page does not have the specified answer for the question: '" + this.textContent + "'");
        $(this).css ("background", "pink");
    }
} );

function getAnswer (questionText) {
    for (var J = answerKey.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
        var zRegExp = new RegExp (answerKey[J].q, 'i');

        if (zRegExp.test (questionText) )
            return answerKey[J].a;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**See [the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBwwn/).**

More information on jQuery selectors can be found in [this part of the doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thank you very very much :) How can i learn javascript like you ?

Comment: You're welcome.  ... Google around.  There's all sorts of tutorials out there. Install the Firebug add-on for Firefox and learn to use it to explore web pages.  Firebug will even show you the CSS/jQuery selectors for a given node.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Nxy9/2/ Can you help me for it ? its actually almost same problem . But i couldnt solve the .each function.

Comment: For this particular code, never use `getElementById`.  You need to use jQuery selectors as per the 2 answers.  `.each()` is a function of jQuery.  If you want help with this new format, save the correct structure with at least 2 sets of questions and answers, so that we may correctly choose the selectors.