# How do I adapt this quiz-answering script to this new quiz layout?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I want the browser to be able to select correct answers to questions.
I found an answer that seems to be the right idea ([How can I automatically select specific radio buttons with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11025270/331508)) but I don't know enough javascript to use it.

My HTML code is shown in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2AzN/).

**Desired output example should look something like this:**
[(Click for larger image)

[image: Desired script result]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nOvd.jpg)

How do I adapt that solution to my target page?

Comment: What's the "@Brock Adams" for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams

Comment: Targeting a user in the title doesn't notify them like it does in a comment.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a forum, addressing questions to specific users is frowned upon, and it is unnecessary.  If the question is clear enough, many people can answer it.  Also, many users monitor the tags that interest them.

Comment: I am understand thanks Brock Adams.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the art is in: (1) identifying the best jQuery selectors for the question and the answers and (2) tuning the `ansForThisQ.each()` loop. For your HTML:

```
var questionTxt = $("span.sorumetin");
```

and

```
var ansForThisQ     = $(this).next ("ul.sorular").find ("a");
ansForThisQ.each ( function () {
    var zRegExp     = new RegExp (answerTxt, 'i');
    if (zRegExp.test (this.textContent) ) {
        bFoundAnswer    = true;
        $(this).css     ("background", "lime");
        return false;   // End loop
    }
} );
```

See [the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2AzN/2/).

Reference and learn [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [jQuery traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Brock Adams. I have two problem that codes. 1)Htlm not refleshing so After the first questions that code not work. 2) How can i select auto correct answer ? this code just underlines that the answer. Thanks.

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dgSskLKV9w

Comment: (1) It looks like the page is loading new questions via AJAX.  That was not reflected in this question, nor in the linked Fiddle. It also adds a new degree of complexity.   (2) The question just implied that you wanted to highlight the correct answer; instead you want the script to click it as well?   ... This question is answered as originally stated.  Mark it answered, and then open a new question with the additional requirements.  Beware that SO is not a script-writing service (although I occasionally do, if it serves my fancy).  We expect evidence of effort and research in Q's.

Comment: It's best, also, that you link to the target page.  That way we can see possible complications up front, and we can test our answer.

Comment: Thanks your helps Brock Adams.. Can you help to me other issue ? I can't do it.  jsfiddle.net/VqQaN/10

Comment: I've already listed my conditions for further help.  Also, this kind of iterative, "Give me teh codez", support-request is frowned on at SO.

Comment: Hey man I am sorry for my questions but I want learn it, How can i always adapt your codes ? Can you learn it me ? I adapted it but it's not work. if you give me hint , i won't write message you again, THANKS Brock Adams... (note: i'am beginner level Javascript )

Comment: I changed necessary "question div" and "answer div" but it's not work :S http://jsfiddle.net/VqQaN/10/

Comment: i think i have problem there. find ("span");

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a ton of time to review your code, but you would probably be easiest to store a variable of 1, 2, 3, or 4, based on the position of the correct answer, then when clicked, simply have 4 nested if statements IE - if 1, highlight 1, if 2, etc.