# How do I click an "answer" link based upon an image source?

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey

I have a simple "Who is" game page and I want to make a simple auto-answer script with Greasemonkey. How can I make that?

Based on the `sid` in the image `src`:

```
<img src="whois_picture.php?yid=123456&sid=3084" />
```

It should click the matching link...

- If `sid=3084`, select answer `d`.
- If `sid=3023`, select answer `a`.
- etc.

Mock up: http://thedudu.com/auto_select/

Key target-page HTML:

```
<div id="whois_guestion">
    <img src="whois_picture.php?yid=123456&sid=3084" />
</div>
<div id="game_options">
    <a href="#" class="game_option">Mickey Mouse</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="a" name="secenekharf" />

    <a href="#" class="game_option">Bugs Bunny</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="b" name="secenekharf" />

    <a href="#" class="game_option">Gofy</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="c" name="secenekharf" />

    <a href="#" class="game_option">Mario</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="d" name="secenekharf" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a legitimate reason for deleting this question, flag it for a moderator's attention. Do not vandalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make an object of `sid`s and answers, like so:

   ```js
   var answerKey   = {
         3084: "d"
       , 3023: "a"
       //etc.
   };
   ```
2. Then use jQuery to select the correct answer link.
3. Finally, send the link a click event.

Here's what a complete script might look like:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Auto-answer script
// @include  http://thedudu.com/auto_select/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var answerKey   = {
      3084: "d"
    , 3023: "a"
    //etc.
};

setTimeout (clickAnswerIfAny, 222); //-- 222 milliseconds

function clickAnswerIfAny () {
    var questImg    = $("#whois_guestion img");
    var questSid    = questImg.attr ("src").replace (/^.+?\bsid=(\d+).*$/i, "$1");
    var answerVal   = answerKey[questSid];
    if (typeof answerVal != "undefined") {
        console.log ("Ans found...");
        //-- Find the <input> with the answer value.
        var answerInp   = $("#game_options input[value='" + answerVal + "']");
        if (answerInp.length) {
            //-- In this case, the link is the previous sibling element.
            var answerLink  = answerInp.prev ();
            console.log (answerInp, answerLink);
            //-- Click the link.
            console.log ("Clicking...");
            var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
            clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
            answerLink[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

See, also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025788/331508).

Comment: Thanks, and no problem.  We all were once.

Comment: @melis, Although it wasn't strictly part of the question, there appears to be a race condition (timing) with that target page.  Adding a slight delay to the script appears to clear it up.  See the modified answer.