# How can adapt that auto-answering code for my HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, greasemonkey

I am beginner javascript about. so I can't adapt that code for my HTML.
Can you adapt it for me ?  and  what is your advise edit these type codes for me?
Thanks.

My code is at [jsfiddle.net/66Lam](http://jsfiddle.net/66Lam).

I have found " [How can I automatically select specific radio buttons with Greasemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025270/how-can-i-automatically-select-specific-radio-buttons-with-greasemonkey) " but don't know enough to adapt it to my target pages, which have HTML like this:

```
<div id="soruareain" class="soruareainimagesiz">
    <div id="sorunodiv">
        <div id="soruno">1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="soruveseceneklerdiv">
        <div id="sorunediv">
            <div id="sorune">Which sport is playing with ball ?</div>
        </div>
        <div id="soruseceneklerdiv">
            <div id="sorusecenekler">
                <div id="cevap1" class="dcevap cevaplaraltalta ">
                    <input type="radio" name="cevapr" id="cevapr1" value="1" class="rcevap"/><span class="lcevap" onclick="sec(1);">athletics </span>
                </div>
                <div id="cevap2" class="dcevap cevaplaraltalta ">
                    <input type="radio" name="cevapr" id="cevapr2" value="2" class="rcevap"/><span class="lcevap" onclick="sec(2);">swimming </span>
                </div>
                <div id="cevap3" class="dcevap cevaplaraltalta ">
                    <input type="radio" name="cevapr" id="cevapr3" value="3" class="rcevap"/><span class="lcevap" onclick="sec(3);">fencing </span>
                </div>
                <div id="cevap4" class="dcevap cevaplaraltalta ">
                    <input type="radio" name="cevapr" id="cevapr4" value="4" class="rcevap"/><span class="lcevap" onclick="sec(4);">Football </span>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cevapadet" id="cevapadet" value="4"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things:

1. Do not address questions to a specific person.  [**Write a quality question**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) instead.  Anyone can answer a good question and I will get alerts for Greasemonkey questions anyway (unless it gets too many downvotes, too fast).
2. It looks like this question will probably be closed soon (and maybe deleted), so **see the code at [jsfiddle.net/66Lam/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/66Lam/8/)** while you can.
3. Please reread [the *How to Ask* page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Note that questions tend to get closed if users feel that no effort was expended, or if the question seems "too localized".
4. This kind of "show me teh codez" question has to be phrased just right or people will close it.

   Stack Overflow is generally not a script-writing service. I only answer this kind of question because:

   1. It's (usually) easy fun, like doing a crossword.
   2. For Greasemonkey scripts, applying the general solution to specific target pages can be a daunting challenge for beginners.
5. To adapt that button code you must learn how [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) relate to HTML, and adjust the code to your target page.  in this case the key changes are:

   ```
   var questionTxt = $("#sorune");
   ```

   and

   ```
   var ansForThisQ = $(this).parent ().nextAll ("div").find ("div.dcevap span.lcevap");
   ```

   and

   ```
   var label       = $(this);
   var radioButt   = label.prevAll ("input");
   ```
6. The answer text should not have leading or trailing spaces.  So, `"Football "` is bad, use `"Football"`.
7. This code requires jQuery, so when making/using jsFiddles, set the jQuery library, see the fiddle I linked.

Comment: a lot of thanks , you are greasemonkey king :) I wish add you on facebook or Can I subscriber you on facebook ?